Kernel module that moves function in place
void make_function_writable(void *addr) {
  unsigned int cr0_register;

  asm volatile("mov %%cr0, %0" : "=r"(cr0_register));

  cr0_register &= ~(1 << 16);

  asm volatile("mov %0, %%cr0" : : "r"(cr0_register));
}

void modified(void) { printk(KERN_INFO "world\n"); }

void hello(void) { printk(KERN_INFO "Hello\n"); }

static int __init hooker_init(void) {

  void (*modified_addr)(void) = &modified;

  make_function_writable(modified_addr);

  memmove(modified_addr + 3, modified_addr, 0x19);
  printk(KERN_INFO "Move");

  void (*modified_addr_new)(void) = (void (*)(void))(modified_addr + 3);

  (modified_addr_new)();

  return 0;
}

static void __exit hooker_exit(void) { return; }

module_init(hooker_init);
module_exit(hooker_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

I created this kernel module and I am getting this error:
unable to handle page fault for address: 3cf741d0
supervisor read access in kernel mode
error_code(0x0000) - not-present page

What is a way to add read access to the function?
I tried set_memory_x and set_memory_rw (and found out that I can't use them in new kernel versions)

Why (oh why) do you want to do this? What about using a function pointer that you can set (e.g.): void (*myfunc)(void) = hello; Then, when you want to change it, just do: myfunc = modified;. Or, just modify the first instruction of hello to be jmp modified. As you have it, the functions must be the same size. And, it's difficult to determine the size(s) at runtime. And, you may have to copy over the literal strings (e.g. "world") as well. Is the code position independent? Even if you do get write access, what you're trying to do is a [bad] hack.

The kernel's own hook functions (kprobe & Co) are using text_poke() for this on x86. It works differently, by temporarily re-mapping the target code as writeable. I haven't read enough of the x86 MMU usage to say why cr0.wp alone gains you nothing ... curious.
